# Vector Space with inner product operation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let (V,$\langle .,. \rangle$) be a finite-dimensional Euclidean space and W ⊂ V a subspace.
Define $W^⊥$ = {x ∈ V | $ \langle x, y \rangle  $ = 0 for all y ∈ W}. You don’t need to show that $W^⊥$
is a subspace of V . Prove V = W ⊕ $W^⊥$

I know you have to use the fact that a set of orthonormal vectors can be extended to an orthonormal basis for a finitely dimensional vector space.
I thought about letting $v_1,...,v_n$ be a basis for W and extend it to the basis of V using the above theorem, then show that the added vectors are a basis of $W^⊥$ but I don't know how to do this and I also don't know how to show it is unique, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure uniqueness of the decomposition, it suffices to proove that $W\cap W^{\perp}=\{0\}$. Let $x\in W\cap W^{\perp}$, in particular, one has $\langle x,x\rangle=0$, which implies $x=0$ using the separation axiom of the dot product. Therefore, one has $\{0\}\subseteq W\cap W^{\perp}$. The converse inclusion being trivial, $W\cap W^{\perp}=\{0\}$.

One is left to show that $V=W+W^{\perp}$. To do so, let $p_W$ be the orthogonal projector on $W$ and let $x\in V$. One has $x=p_W(x)+x-p_W(x)$, with $p_W(x)\in W$ and I let you show that $x-p_W(x)\in W^{\perp}$.

**Hint.** The is the case if and only if $x-p_W(x)\in\ker(p_W)$.

Comment: I have never heard of an 'orthogonal projector' and so I doubt I would be able to use it in my solution.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a *projector* onto a subvector space with respect to another?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I believe we are supposed to do it using the theorem I stated if thats any help but obviously the uniqueness proof still works.

Comment: If $(w_1,\cdots,w_r)$ is an orthonormal basis for $W$ and $(w_1,\cdots,w_r,w_{r+1},\cdots,w_n)$ is a basis for $V$. If $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in V$, then $p_W(x)=(x_1,\cdots,x_r,0,\cdots,0)$. This is how one defines the orthogonal projection onto $W$ using the theorem you stated. Hope that is clear.

Comment: I still don't really understand it, is there any other way you can do it using different notation?

Comment: Sure, if $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, let $w=(x_1,\cdots,x_r,0,\cdots,0)$ and $w^{\perp}=(0,\cdots,0,x_{r+1},\cdots,x_n)$, one has $x=w+w^{\perp}$ and $w\in W,w^{\perp}\in W^{\perp}$. The decomposition is still in the basis I defined above.

Comment: Ah okay yeah I understand that, thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: Sorry one last thing, showing $x-p_W(x)\in\ker(p_W)$ is it correct to just say that when subtracting $p_W(x)$  this effectively cancels out all of the coefficients for the basis of W so they become all zero and therefore its in the kernel?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what that means!

Comment: Okay thank you so much, I'll just change the projector notation into the notation above, sorry for asking so many questions!

Comment: This is my pleasure!